# Configure vsftpd for secure file transfer

Tags: vsftpd

I set up the `vsftpd` server following instructions from web searches and this worked until I tried to secure it.

I have checked all directory names and edited, uninstalled, reinstalled the server numerous times. I have allowed access to all ports, ensured only root is owner of the `.conf` files, given my user permissions for a directory on the home network and added them to the user list file, and now I am out of ideas.

The error I seem to be getting is `code=exited, status=2`. Apologies in advance if I have missed something, but here are my files:

**Ports:**

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20:21/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
30000:31000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
990                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20:21/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
30000:31000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
990 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**My `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file:**

```
listen=NO

listen_ipv6=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

chroot_local_user=YES

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES

user_sub_token=$USER

local_root=/home/$USER/ftp

pasv_enable=YES

pasv_min_port=30000

pasv_max_port=31000

pasv_address=127.0.0.1

userlist_enable=YES

userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list

userlist_deny=NO
```

Comment: You should set listen=yes and ipv6=no. Also you should firstly disable ssl. Then make a systemctl start vsftpd and post the output.

Comment: Another sugestion would be to forget vsftpd and switch to sftp using SSH. It is included in openSSH.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thomas. I made the changes you suggested to the .conf file but unfortunately no luck still. This is the output when i disable SSL:

Comment: vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-28 23:18:33 +07; 23s ago
    Process: 2517 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited>
   Main PID: 2518 (vsftpd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9346)
     Memory: 592.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
             └─2518 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf

Comment: Remove this settings too. pasv_address=127.0.0.1, chroot_local_user=YES, secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

Answer (score 0):

This is my setting that works for me.

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
idle_session_timeout=600
data_connection_timeout=120
ftpd_banner=Welcome to FTP service.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
pam_service_name=vsftpd
ssl_enable=NO
utf8_filesystem=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```